# Using sed to combine multiple csv files

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I have 3 csv files I'd like to combine. Each file has 3 comma delimited columns.

```
File 1 has columns a,b,c
File 2 has columns d,e,f
File 3 has columns g,h,i
```

I'd like to combine the 3 files into a single file of:

```
a,b,c,e,f,h
```

Can I use sed to do that?

I could write a console app or script easily enough but I'm attempting to get some sed skills and believe this should be a suitable task?

Comment: what is your criteria for combining? why do you leave out "d","g","i" ?

Comment: Do you need to join on certain columns (so perhaps a = d)?  If so, then you need to look at the `join` command (one of the odder commands in the Unix universe).  Remember that the data needs to be in a sorted order, and decide what to do if there is no matching value in one of the files (an outer join in DBMS parlance).  Otherwise, if it is purely positional (row 1 in file one goes with row 1 in file 2 and row 1 in file 3), then the paste and cut commands shown below are good.  Using 'sed' is hard (at best); it processes one file at a time, not 3 in parallel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or just cut and paste:

```
paste -d ',' file[123] | cut -d ',' -f 1,2,3,5,6,8
```

Comment: Thanks!  Symmetry is pretty :)

Comment: +1 - but be aware that if there are commas embedded in any of the data fields, all hell will break loose.

Comment: PS: You would find that [CSVFIX](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) can handle the pasted-together file even if there are embedded commas in fields.

Comment: That's some nice code kung-fu! Any hints on how to get rid of the end of line chars after the 3 & 6 fields? They're breaking the excel import.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
paste file[123] | sed 's/\t/,/g' | cut -d',' -f 1,2,3,5,6,8
```

Answer (score 1):

Mat Mendel's answer is good to go unless you happen to be on Windows using cygwin in which case some annoying end of line character quirks come into play. This is down to the unix command utilities, in this case paste and cut, using \n as the end of line character instead of the \r\n that Windows wants.

I couldn't qucikly work out how to change the end of line character for those utils or cygwin in general so I was happily able to make use of sed after all.

```
paste -d ',' file1 file2 file3 | sed 's/\r//g' | cut -d ',' -f 1,2,3,5,6,8 | sed 's/$/\r/'
```

Comment: Ah yes, the extra '\r' issue.  Nice to see you solved it!

You could use tr -d '\r', instead of the first sed command.

Don't get me wrong, sed is awesome, but a bit heavy weight for some tasks. :)

Comment: is the problem newlines in the middle or at the end? you could use dos2unix or unix2dos to correct that also.